# Print the Marklogic Search Query

Tags: marklogic

How can I print the complete query which is being executed in MarkLogic?

```
val jsonDocManager = dbClient.newJSONDocumentManager()
var newDocPage = jsonDocManager.search(queryDef, 20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the query options in the query definition and, in the query options, set the debug option to true.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_68047

Hoping that helps,